# What is the convenient way to connectorize these butterfly laser diode pads?

Tags: diodes

I want to use the +LD -LD pads of [this](https://picolas.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/BFPS-VRHSP_02_Manual_Rev1905.pdf) very short pulse driver for another laser diode whose pinout does not match to this driver.

Below shows pads/pins of the laser diode where I want to access two of them(anode and cathode to drive another laser diode):

[image]

I thought about soldering an SMA cable's wires to the driver's +LD -LD pads and then couple it to the laser I need to use.

Would that cause any sort of problems or are there any adapters for such purpose?

Comment: The added stray inductance of any wires or connector is likely to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet:

> The maximum internal stray impedance must not exceed ~ 10 nH to achieve best performance

That's less than 1 cm, so you'll need to keep your leads extremely short, at least if you expect sub-nanosecond pulses.

Your best bet is probably to make an adapter PCB that reorders the laser diode pins and then solder that into the existing footprint.